# Writing business logic in view

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc, html, website-performance

Can writing business logic in the view(.cshtml) of an MVC application have an impact on performance (for example, Load time)? Is it the preferable way or are there any other best practices?

Comment: I feel that it is important to point out that 'best practice' does not solely focus on performance as your question would perhaps suggest. Best practices take other considerations, such as the maintainability of your project, separation of concerns, readability and so on. You should be taking these into consideration as much as, if not more than solely performance.

Answer (score 2):

Writing any logic in a view is an anti pattern.

When writing mvc you need to create a model that matches your ui 100%. This model will be separate from your db model.

You should utilise editortemplated and displaytemplates whenever you have a list of something in your model. If you have a list of Foo called foos do a

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foos)
```

Which will invoke the editor template for Foo for all elements in the list. If you see yourself doing a foreach you are probably doing something wrong. Continue this N levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Esben already pointed out in his answer: it is really not a good idea to put business logic in a view, because it goes against the design principle of an [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

- the View shows the model content to the user
- the Controller manages the interaction input to manipulate the model or change the view
- the Model manages the domain data and logic.

Business logic in the view is a bad practice that is to be avoided.

**Additional thoughts**

When we say business logic, it's really something that is related to the model content (e.g. "higher than average", "the biggest", ...) and not just about how to present the model data (for example a mapping between values and colors).

If your model is managed in another system process (cshtml in one process  vs. model logic and db accesses in another process), or if modell access implies involvement of another server, then doing business logic in the view would require many more expensive API calls/requests (e.g. more network latency, more data transfers, same data read several times), than if the needed logic would be already factored inside the model.